# Use xml documentation from Nuget package

Tags: c#, .net, xml, swagger, nuget

I have an SDK nuget package with models and XML documentation for them with the following csproj configuration:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <RepositoryUrl>url</RepositoryUrl>
    <PackageReadmeFile>README.md</PackageReadmeFile>
    <PackageReleaseNotes>notes</PackageReleaseNotes>
    <Description>description</Description>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>True</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <Version>4.2.0</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="..\README.md">
      <Pack>True</Pack>
      <PackagePath>\</PackagePath>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I also have a Web API project (**net6.0**) with a swagger that uses this SDK nugget package and needs SDK.xml file to describe models. I can see this XML file in lib (in users/me/.nuget):
[image]

I searched for some solutions but nothing helped me. How I can import this XML file into my Web API and refer to it in the swagger config?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a working solution - just put this into csproj configuration of my Web API:

```
 <Target Name="_ResolveCopyLocalNuGetPkgXmls" AfterTargets="ResolveReferences">
    <ItemGroup><!-- Copy XML files from all PackageReferences to output dir -->
      <ReferenceCopyLocalPaths Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).xml')"
      Condition="'%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.NuGetPackageId)'!='' and Exists('%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).xml')" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

The only problem here is that it won't work in pipelines (I guess)